# Coq - I have to define a function that is only true if x and y are different, I also have to prove the definition

Tags: coq

here is my attempt at defining diffb.  diffb x y returns true, if x <> y and false otherwise.

```
Definition diffb (b c : bool) : bool :=
match b, c with
| true, false => true
| false, true => true
| false, false => false
| true, true => false
end.
```

I have attempted above to define diffb, though I'm not sure if it is correct :(, I also need to prove diffb:

```
Theorem diffb_correct : forall a b : bool, 
  a <> b <-> diffb a b = true.
```

Though I'm not sure what to do when diffb appears throughout my subgoals.

thanks

lucio

edit. Solved it :)

here it is

```
Definition diffb (b c : bool) : bool :=
match b, c with
| true, false => true
| false, true => true
| false, false => false
| true, true => false
end.
```

(* Now prove that your function satisfies the specification. *)

```
Theorem diffb_correct : forall a b : bool, 
  a <> b <-> diffb a b = true.
intro a.
destruct a.
intro b.
destruct b.
split.
intro c.
destruct c.
reflexivity.
intro d.
discriminate.
split.
intro e.
reflexivity.
intro f.
discriminate.
intro g.
destruct g.
split.
intro h.
reflexivity.
discriminate.
split.
intro i.
destruct i.
reflexivity.
discriminate.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `diffb` function seems completely fine. Since it is defined by case analysis on its argument, your proof will have to follow the same path. Instead of a complete script, I'll give you two advices:

- You might want to learn about the tactics `case` and `destruct` to perform the case analysis.
- And have a look at `unfold` or `simpl` to replace `diffb` by its definition and simplify it after analysis.

Cheers,
V.

Comment: Great job ! Just for fun, here is a one-liner for your goal `Theorem diffb_correct : forall a b : bool, 
  a <> b <-> diffb a b = true.
Proof.
destruct a; destruct b; intros; simpl in *; intuition; try discriminate.
Qed.`